# I configured aws-amplify sdk for cognito sign up around 6 months back.I want update it for social sign-up (google)

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

if i execute the command "amplify update auth" i'm getting an error "You are not working inside a valid Amplify project" .this is the issue what i'm facing from past 3-days

[image]

Comment: Do you see the amplify folder?

Comment: @dfranca, no i didn't see any of amplify folders.